# java Could not compile stylesheet containing dyn:evaluate

Tags: java, xslt, dynamic

I'm having troubles running an xslt transformation in java. My xslt file contains some dyn:evaluate functions.

My java code is:

```
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(CONFIG + transformerFileName));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File(XML_SAMPLE_FILE));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File(transformedFileName)));
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'evaluate' is not a valid object reference.' 
FATAL ERROR: 'Could not compile stylesheet'
```

It seems that default java processor does not support dynamic functions. Is there any library I should add in order to have this xslt transformation run in java?

Thanks,

Laura

Comment: Frankly as you seem to develop with Java I would consider moving to XSLT 3 with the help of Saxon 9.8 (available in the open-source HE edition on Maven and Sourceforge) and then to use the XSLT standard `xsl:evaluate` element instead of the `dyn:evaluate` extension function. Relying on XSLT 1 and its extensions if pure standard XSLT 3 is available seems like the wrong choice. As for getting `dyn:evaluate` to work, your previous posts sounded as if you had it working so somehow you used Xalan before and need to make sure your program uses it as well if you want to use that function.

Comment: I tested My xslt with eclipse embedded xslt engine. I cannot move to xslt 3 because my project runs with java 6.

Comment: Does your Java 1.6 version allow you to use `TransformerFactory factory = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl()`?  I think earlier versions of the JRE have both versions of Xalan internalized so you could try that. If that class is not available then you need to use Xalan 2.7 from apache.org as a library of your project and instantiate `TransformerFactory factory = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();` to have `dyn:evaluate` support I think.

Comment: @Laura Saxon 9.8 works with Java 6.

Comment: Tank you all! I tested Saxon 9.8  but I got the following error: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: xsl:evaluate is not available in this configuration. Then I tested my xslt with Xalan 2.7 from apache.org as a library and it worked fine!